# reach variable in connect by PLSQL

Tags: sql, select, plsql

can anybody explain me why i get invalid identifier error and why cannot be variable z.cupu reachable?

```
 ORA-00904: "Z"."CUPU": invalid identifier

select 
 (select listagg(text, ', ') within group (order by kod)
                    from cis_chyby_pu_na_uss 
                    where kod in (
                        select 
                        regexp_substr(t.stav_full, '[^,]+', 1, l.lev) split
                        from PREKLAPANIE_PU_NA_USS_HIST t, (select rownum as lev 
                                                            from dual 
                                                            connect by level <= length (trim(regexp_replace((select stav_full 
                                                                                                            from PREKLAPANIE_PU_NA_USS_HIST h 
                                                                                                            where z.cupu = h.cislo_pu)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
                                                                                                            , '[^,]+')))
                                                            ) l

                        where t.cislo_pu = z.cupu
                        and z.stav <> 100)

    )
    from zz_2202 z
```

Comment: There is no PL/SQL in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab as 
(select 1 n from dual)
select * from tab root 
where n in (select child1.n from tab child1 
             where child1.n in (select child2.n from tab child2 
                                 where child2.n = root.n));
```

OK

```
with tab as 
(select 1 n from dual)
select (select * from tab child1 where child1.n = root.n)
from tab root;
```

OK

```
with tab as 
(select 1 n from dual)
select (select * from (select * from tab child2 where child2.n = root.n))
from tab root;
```

ERROR

So there is a limit for nesting in the select list which seems to be equal to 1.

> Oracle performs a correlated subquery when a nested subquery
>   references a column from a table referred to a parent statement one
>   level above the subquery. The parent statement can be a SELECT,
>   UPDATE, or DELETE statement in which the subquery is nested. A
>   correlated subquery conceptually is evaluated once for each row
>   processed by the parent statement. However, the optimizer may choose
>   to rewrite the query as a join or use some other technique to
>   formulate a query that is semantically equivalent. Oracle resolves
>   unqualified columns in the subquery by looking in the tables named in
>   the subquery and then in the tables named in the parent statement.